# magento add delete checkbox to attribute

Tags: magento

I've created new catalog attribute which is pdf file upload, everything works well, but after upload, or refresh it showing nothing.
My question is how to add box with name or something to now that this is already uploaded, and check box which checked will delete this attribute - exacly the same as is in images upload. 
I thought maybe create public function afterLoad($object), but what inside, how to add this details?

Enybody have idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check for attributes input_renderer. In the renderer you can add custom code and js which is needed...